# How to prevent word wrapping when there are white-spaces in the text

Tags: css

I have this code to show category names. I have a problem with word-wrapping when there are two words with a space in between them.

Here is the CSS:

```
.post-item .cat {
height: 25px;
display: inline-block;
background: #CC0000;
font-size: 11px;
padding-left: 10px;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 23px;
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

It show me the category name on 2 lines.

I want the text in one line like this:

```
picture news
```

And not like this:

```
picture
  new
```

Ex:

[image]

Comment: `.picture, .news { ... }`  ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
.dont-break-the-line {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Comment: @user3915307 Have you tried simply increasing the width of the container (`.post-item .cat`) so that the text would fit?

Comment: i try, but when i have word like ( sport cat ) the background with width is big than text, So i need Sentence, along with fit tape